# Property 'push' does not exist on type '() => void'. How to resolve this error in Typescript Angular 10?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular10

I am getting this error when I use push() on the array in an Angular 10 project in Typescript.

**Error**

```
Property 'push' does not exist on type '() => void'.ts(2339)
```

Please help me figure out why this error is coming and how can I resolve it?

```
export class GrantProgramComponent implements OnInit {
  grantProgramForms : any = this.fb.array([]); 
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.AddGrantProgramForms(); 
  }


  AddGrantProgramForms(){
    this.AddGrantProgramForms.push(this.fb.group({
      Id : [0], 
      ProgramName : [''], 
      ProgramCode : [''], 
      StartDate : [''],
      EndDate : [''], 
      Status : [false]
    })); 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the formbuilder before it's been initialised in the constructor. Move your logic into the constructor method:

```
 grantProgramForms : any 

 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder ) {
   this.grantProgramForms = this.fb.array([]); 
 }
```

Then in your `addGrantProgramForms` method you are referencing the wrong variable, I think you mean `this.grantProgramForms.push` not `this.AddGrantProgramForms.push`

Comment: Thanks! I was calling the method instead of the array lol. A stupid mistake from my part.

Comment: No worries, it happens. Glad it's working now!

Comment: If there's no other problems you can feel free to mark this as solved